# Test class for deleting a record in a custom related list is not working

Tags: unit-test

I am trying to test a method in my code where I delete a selected record, but any possible change I made in my test method is not working.

The method in my APEX class is this:

```
global List<Solicitud_de_contacto__c> getSolInfos() {

    integer limitPlusOne = PageSize + 1;

    solinfos = [Select id, Name, Nombre_de_candidato__r.Name, Correo_electr_nico__c, CreatedDate, Estado_de_alumno__c from Solicitud_de_contacto__c where Nombre_de_candidato__r.id = : accountId and Numero_de_Intenciones_estudio_Postgrado__c > 0 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC, Id DESC LIMIT :limitPlusOne];

    return solinfos;
}

public void DeleteSolInfo()
{
    // if for any reason we are missing the reference 
    if (SelectedSolInfoId == null) {

        return;
    }

    // find the Sol Info record within the collection
    Solicitud_de_contacto__c tobeDeleted = null;
    for(Solicitud_de_contacto__c solinfo : solinfos)
        if (solinfo.Id == SelectedSolInfoId) {
            tobeDeleted = solinfo;
            break;
        }

        //if Sol Info record found delete it
        if (tobeDeleted != null) {
            Delete tobeDeleted;
        }

        //refresh the data
        LoadSolInfoData();
    }
}
```

So, I am trying to test the DeleteSolInfo() method this way:

```
@isTest static void DeleteSolInfoTest() {
    CreateAccount();
    CreatePostgrado();
    CreateSolInfo();
    CreateIntencionEstudios();


    RelatedListsPostgrado controller = new RelatedListsPostgrado();

    Test.startTest();
    controller.Pagesize=5;
    controller.getSolInfos();
    controller.DeleteSolInfo();
    controller.LoadSolInfoData();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

It only covers the part:

```
 if (SelectedSolInfoId == null) {

     return;
```

I tried to cover the rest and made thousand changes, tested and the coverage stays the same always, so the rest is not being covered. The last change I made is what I am showing above.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me some tips or where do I have to amend my test class, so the test coverage goes up?.

Comment: You never provide a value to `SelectedSolInfoId` in your test class, but depend on the value in your method.

Comment: Thanks for responding battery.cord. It is declared as public string SelectedSolInfoId { get; set; }. Which value should it have for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a value in `SelectedSolInfoId`, but never provide a value to your controller, preventing your test from running past a certain point.

This is a common pattern used to pass data from a visualforce page via an `actionFunction` or other similar component. The value is passed from the page, to the controller, before the function is called, in effect, creating a parameter out of a controller variable. Without a page to provide this value, you are required to provide it yourself in the test.

You would set the value of `SelectedSolInfoId` to any valid id to be used by your delete method. I would suggest creating a few records, then deleting each one, checking to make sure they were deleted using `System.assert`.

---

The way you are talking about this class leads me to believe you did not write it yourself. If this is one of your first attempts at writing apex code, I would highly suggest trying some of the [trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en) salesforce provides as a training method, before trying to cover someone else's classes, or write your own.

I would also suggest reading [other questions about test classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=test%20coverage%20) on this site, and to do some reading on proper `assert` usage before trying to design tests.

Comment: Thank you very much. My coverage is now 84%. I could amend it with help of your advice. I have read your statements as well. In fact, I am not an expert in programming and not considered a developer myself, but learning something on the way.